# Firebase notifications are not sending as high priority

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-notifications

When I send a notification to my Android device through the Firebase web interface, the notification doesn't peek down from the status bar. If I want to see the notification, I must swipe down. This occurs even when I have the priority set to `High` in the web interface. Why is this?

This is not an issue if the notification arrives when the app is open because I can set the priority myself in my `FirebaseMessagingService` class:

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

  @Override public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
    sendNotification("Message Body");

  }

  /**
   * Create and show a simple notification containing the received FCM message.
   *
   * @param messageBody FCM message body received.
   */
  private void sendNotification(String messageBody) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, SubscribedActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_push_notification)
        .setContentTitle("FCM Message")
        .setContentText(messageBody)
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
        .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.color_accent))
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
        (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
  }
}
```

Comment: The code seems okay. Maybe this behavior is device specific. Have you tried testing with different devices?

Comment: @AL. The code is working as expected. The issue is, that code is only executed if a notification is received while the app is in the foreground. The issue occurs when a notification is received while the app is in the background. I have tried on both a Google Pixel XL and a Nexus 6P. Thank you for your help.

Comment: As I understand, when your app is in foreground, the code above is executed as expected (generates a notification which *peeks down* from the status bar). When in background, it only shows an icon in the status bar. And the issue is the behavior when on background. The way I see it, it is the expected behavior. Notifications sent thru the Firebase Console is treated as a Notification Message, wherein if a Notification Message is sent when the app is in background, the device itself would handle how to display it. https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When the app is open, you are handling your own notification and therefore you can control what it does. However, when the app is in background, the notification is handled by system tray and the only priority paramaters you can pass from the web console are high and normal. Passing the prority as high however will not work as intended if the users don't interact with your app. [Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#setting-the-priority-of-a-message)

> High priority messages generally should result in user interaction with your app. If FCM detects a pattern in which they don't, your messages may be de-prioritized.