# FCM Push notifications does not show heads display on notification on top of screen

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

We are using firebase push notification in Android and in iOS. The push is sent using FCM REST API call. Push type is `notification` with extra `data` node.

Here is a sample payload:

```
{ 
  "notification" : {
    "title": "title text",
    "body": "message body text",
    "sound": "default"
  },
  "data":  {
    "messageType": "xxx"
  },
  "to": "yyy",
  "priority": "high",
  "time_to_live": 0
}
```

This type of push notification does not show a heads up display when the app is in background and phone is on. -- Notification just are added to notifications bar but are not sneak peaked to user at the top of the screen. -- no matter if the current app is full screen app or not.

One solution that I have tried and is working is to shift to pure `data` message where we will not send any `notification` node, but just the `data` node and write the code to show notification ourselves and set notification priority to Max (ie `.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)`) on notification builder object. 
But this seems to have issues on iOS where `data` only pushes are not received/shown to user if the app killed by user.

So is there any workaround to this? any solution that works on Android, but also does not break iOS.

Comment: @mallaudin thanks but thats different.

Comment: what about data messages ?

Comment: Related question (unfortunately also without answers): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41528315/firebase-notifications-are-not-sending-as-high-priority

Comment: @AamirAbro, what do you mean by `but are not sneak peaked to user at the top of the screen` ? Can you also post android code also?

Comment: @ArindamNayak that means that id does not show any heads up display.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the NotificationPriority to PRIORITY_HIGH or PRIORITY_MAX for Android to show the notification. See [Android Notification](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages/#androidnotification) and [Notification Priority](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages#NotificationPriority) for more details.

You should set these values using the constants, not using the strings. E.g.

```
{
  token,
  android: {
    notification:
    {
      title,
      body,
      // See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification#PRIORITY_MAX.
      // This is deprecated in Android API level 26, but works for older versions.
      notification_priority: 2,
      // Always allow Android users to see the message in its entirety.
      // See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification#VISIBILITY_PUBLIC
      visibility: 1
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I think that you should put a string not an int, otherwise you will get this error:
TypeError: notification.visibility.toUpperCase is not a function
So I think that the best is using something like:
visibility: "public" or visibility:"2"

Info source: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options?hl=es